# Testcontainers runs tests in container (Jenkins container) could not connect to Ryuk

Tags: docker, jenkins, testcontainers

I have got a container with Jenkins. I am trying to run tests pipeline inside this container. Tests uses Testcontainers. I am struggling with error:

```
18:36:15.560 [testcontainers-ryuk] WARN org.testcontainers.utility.RyukResourceReaper - Cannot connect to Ryuk at 172.17.0.1:55592
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
    at org.testcontainers.utility.RyukResourceReaper.lambda$null$0(RyukResourceReaper.java:92)
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.ratelimits.RateLimiter.doWhenReady(RateLimiter.java:27)
    at org.testcontainers.utility.RyukResourceReaper.lambda$maybeStart$1(RyukResourceReaper.java:88)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Jenkins container was run by command

`docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -p 8080:8080 -p 5000:5000 -d --restart always <img>`

I've tried to run Jenkins container with `--network="host"` but same effect.

When I am running those tests directly on my local machine by `mvn clean verify`, tests passed and this error didn't occur.

EDIT:

I've changed network to `bridge` (`--network="bridge"`) for Jenkins container. In test I used explicite network `bridge`:

```
new GenericContainer("mongodb:1..").withNetworkMode("bridge")...
```

Ryuk container is created (I can see three containers on my host docker - jenkins, mongo, ryuk) and when I run `docker network inspect bridge` I can see three containerers are attatched to it. But when I am trying connect to Ryuk container using `gateway` (`172.17.0.1`) from Jenkins container using telenet it is NOT possible. But when I am using Ryuk IP (`172.17.0.2`) instead of `gateway`'s IP I can connect. Then I've create other container on my host and tryied to connect to it form Jenkins container via `gateway`'s IP - could do it.

**SOLUTION**

Just run Jenkins container with `-v /var/run/docker.sock.raw:/var/run/docker.sock` instead of `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`.
Thanks @Kevin Wittek!

Comment: Which OS and which Docker variant are you using? The error `172.17.0.1:55592` sometimes indicates issues with firewall rules. Does the Ryuk container come up successfully?

Comment: Checked on macOs and Widows (WSL2 Ubuntu). I've edited post - look at edit.

Comment: I think you are running into this issue:
https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/4395

Can you please try this workaround?
https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/4395#issuecomment-1308814353

Comment: That's great, thanks for sharing. I will post my comment as a more detailed answer for better future discoverability :)

Comment: I have the same issue on WSL2 as well as on linux sometimes. I don't use docker desktop. Issue starts to come in some cases, then there is a chance that I can't make it work for a day. Then out of nowhere after a day it starts to work again. Docker prunes and restarts doesn't help.

Comment: I don't know how the mentioned -v parameter thing can help. First of all, I am not running this INSIDE another container, it still gets whacked, for instance with IntelliJ. So I can't set anything for it. I can't even set this parametrization for the testcontainer either, since this is programmatic Java usage, not a command line thing.

Comment: Second, I really hate that this -v option is shown everywhere, but nobody questions it. How on Earth does it make sense, that "something" is working almost all the time, then it's not, but a command line option would help to make it work all the time? Then why it works without that setting in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in one of the comments, this originates from [an issue](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/4395) in Testcontainers for Java regarding an upstream change in Docker Desktop (see [this issue](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/5588#issuecomment-934600089)).

The current workaround for Mac is to mount the raw socket when creating the container:

```
-v /var/run/docker.sock.raw:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: not only for Mac, docker on Windows as well it works

Comment: U've missed `k` in `.sock`

Comment: @MMC you confirmed it works on Windows as well? That would be super awesome, some time ago it did not work on Windows AFAIK.

Comment: How on Earth can I add such parameters to testcontainers, if it is doing everything itself in the background? I'm just trying to spin up a container with it, it downloads, it runs it however it wants. By the way, isn't that strange, that something (running testcontainers) work as usual for days or weeks on a machine, then this kind of issue starts to surface and it takes a day of docker network prune, restarts etc, when it starts to work again, BUT you say that an option makes it work all the time? How it works without this setting in the first place then?